# How to shift each row of 2d array incremently

Tags: java

```
import java.util.*;
class Main1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int [][] twoDim = new int [n][n];
        int a = (twoDim.length);
        int b = (twoDim[0].length);

        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                twoDim[i][j] = j % n;
                System.out.print(twoDim[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }

    }
}
```

I have just started learning java and I want to output something like this:

```
0 1 2
1 0 1
2 1 0
```

In this case user input was 3
I know how to get something like this:

```
0 0 0
1 1 1
2 2 2
```

or like this:

```
0 1 2
0 1 2
0 1 2
```

but I don't know how to shift each row incrementally with modular.
If I missed the answer, I sincerely apologize.

Comment: please include your code

Comment: Change `(j + i) % n;` to `Math.abs(j - i) % n`;

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve], which can be compiled and tested by others. Show the result you want to get when executing your code and the result you are actually getting. Describe the output you want or explain in detail what you mean by "shift each row". Maybe show a bigger example than using `3` as input.

Comment: create separate function for displaying matrix and moving items within the matrix.

Comment: Susmit Agrawal, thanks man, that's works! :)

Answer (score 0):

```
import java.util.*;
class Main1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = scan.nextInt();
        int [][] twoDim = new int [n][n];

        int a = (twoDim.length);
        int b = (twoDim[0].length);

        for(int i = 0; i < a; i++){
            for(int j = 0; j < b; j++) {
                twoDim[i][j] = Math.abs(j - i) % n;
                System.out.print(twoDim[i][j] + " ");
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```